# Partition Sum without shuffling

Tags: algorithm

In an interview question I was given a slightly different version of the partition sum problem: you are given an array, find the partition index such that the sum of the left array is equal to the sum of the right array. Here, we cannot shuffle elements to form a partition

for example: [5,1,8,2,2,9,1]

5 + 1 + 8 = 2 + 2 + 9 + 1 = 14

9 + 5 = 8 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 but that is not a valid answer to this problem because we cannot shuffle elements.

I said that we can make a left sum and right sum, left array and right array. 
Start with leftsum = 5 (sum of first element) and right sum = 23 (sum of all the other elements). Then loop through the right array and keep checking if the left sum = right sum. If not, subtract the first element in the right array and add it to the left array. Here, it would be leftsum = 5 + 1 = 6, rightsum = 23 - 1 = 22.

Similarly:
leftsum = 6 + 8 = 14, rightsum = 22 - 8 = 14
since leftsum = rightsum, we return the partition index as 2

If we reach the end of the right array it means the partition doesn't exist and we return invalid.

Even though the interviewer said the answer seems right he did not seem satisfied with my solution. Is there a more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: You have `O(n)` time and `O(1)` extra memory. I don't see how it could get better than that.

Comment: Is it possible he thought you were proposing actually removing elements from the right array and appending them to the left array (as opposed to simply using indexes into the single original array)?

Comment: In the beginning I did propose deleting elements from the right array but then I saw there was an error with that so I used indices instead.

Comment: Are negative numbers allowed?

Comment: Are fractional numbers allowed?

Comment: He didn't say they weren't, so I am assuming they are allowed. If they are not allowed, the algorithm I mentioned above can be modified to: if we reach a point where leftsum > rightsum we return no such partition. But I'm not sure how to improve this algorithm...

Comment: No we're just dealing with an array of integers

Answer (score 0):

The time/space complexity of your algorithm is optimal, but:

- Part of the goal of such questions is to see what further questions you ask. In this case you could have asked (if not yet specified) whether:

  - the numbers are all integers, or fractional numbers can occur
  - the numbers are all non-negative, or negative numbers can occur
- When you mention *left* and *right* arrays, you give the impression the solution deals with 2 separate array variables. Also *subtracting from* and *adding to* arrays strengthens the idea you allocate and deallocate memory as you change the size of two different arrays. This would not be efficient and could even be interpreted as using *O(n)* space.
- Your solution uses two sums when it could be done with one.
- A key observation is that if the sum of all values is *n*, then the partitions should both yield a sum of *n/2*. If you have one partition with that sum, then obviously the other has that sum also. Furthermore, if the values are guaranteed to be integers, *n* should be even. If it is odd you could stop looking further as there is no solution.

So the algorithm for signed integers could be represented like this:

```
sum = 0
for i = 0 to len(array)-1:
    sum = sum + array[i]
if sum % 2 == 1:
    return -1      # no solution
sum = sum / 2
for i = 0 to len(array)-1:
    if sum == 0:
        return i   # solution
    sum = sum - array[i]
return -1    # no solution
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/FM5Y/1)

Note there can be multiple solutions (e.g. with input `[0,0,0,0]` or [5,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,5]`). The algorithm will just return the first one it finds.

If it would be given that the values are always non-negative then you could use this algorithm, which could run a bit faster (but not with a different time complexity) as it visits the array values only once:

```
sum = 0
left = 0
right = len(array) - 1
while left <= right:
    if sum < 0:
        sum = sum + array[left]
        left = left + 1
    else:
        sum = sum - array[right]
        right = right - 1
if sum = 0:
    return left  # solution
return -1      # no solution
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/FM5Y)

Comment: I think the interviewer was also looking for edge cases and when to return immediately .I didn't do any checks in the beginning to see if there was no partition (i.e. checking if sum was odd), which was probably why he did not seem satisfied. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see how having negative integers or floating point effects the answer of OP. -1

Comment: @SaeedAmiri, I did not say it affected the answer of the OP, but it allows for more optimised algorithms when you *know* the specs better. I interview people myself as part of my job, and seeing how people ask for more details is an interesting aspect in evaluating someone's capabilities.

Comment: When I say I don't see how it effects, I already considered optimised version.

Comment: The OP said in comments that he did not get info on whether only non-negative numbers are allowed, and so this means he might have left out an opportunity for a better algorithm *if* it had turned out that the numbers would never be negative.

Comment: In fact the thing you call it optimised version (OPs answer), always works. Regardless of positive or negative numbers, fractional or integers. I think this answer should be deleted.

Comment: @trincot, whatever comment the OP left doesn't help to make your answer reasonable. If he has extra comments, he could make them a new question and you can answer them.

Comment: I agree the OP's algorithm always works. The question was not to provide a working algorithm, but to see if there is room for efficiency gains, which I provided, while explaining that these improvements do no change the time complexity of the OP's algorithm.

Comment: You didn't provide any efficiency improvement. Your first algorithm is just a trivial dumb algorithm, the second algorithm is just OPs algorithm and you didn't even understand that it works regardless of negative or positive. "If it would be given that the values are always non-negative then you could use this algorithm". This answer definitely should have negative votes.

Comment: I just notice that your implementation of the second algorithm is wrong. Your right should start at len/2, and every time should increment it or decrease it depending to situations. Far from working correct algorithm.

Comment: Allow me to disagree: an algorithm that uses fewer variables, and visits items fewer times, will run faster. While agreeing that this does not change the time complexity. The last algorithm I provided does *not* work for negative values -- which is why I put it like that. The OP's algorithm *does* work for negative values, which I never said it didn't. The difference is that if you know more about the problem, you can gain in execution times and memory. NB: your proposal for "correcting" the second algorithm would in fact break it: there is no guarantee that the answer is n/2.

Comment: My fix suggestion was correct, we increament or decreament per requirement. But I noticed your second algorithm is actually correct.

Comment: If you edit the answer (e.g. removing fractional part). I'll remove my downvote. We could also remove the comments. Just ping me. I was biased that your improved algorithm is wrong.

Comment: The topic of fractional numbers is relevant to my answer: when you know fractional numbers are allowed, then the algorithm cannot be further optimized, but when they are *not* allowed (which happens to be the case from reading OP's comments), one can add a bail-out odd/even test, which would give a slightly faster response in 50% of (randomly distributed) input of signed integers. NB: your correction to the 2nd algorithm is really wrong: you cannot assume that starting at index n/2 is correct. That index has no special role. How would that work for input like `[3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`?

Comment: My correction was based on the fact that we know the average of the sum, it was a bit faster than naive algorithm in average. When you don't have exact information, it is better to not talk about it. BTW I don't see how do you improve with information about existence of fractional algorithm. Please edit your answer and put your explanation as an algorithm there.

Comment: If by fractional you mean if the sum over two is fractional then we avoid it, in my opinion it is stupid. While one can write an algorithm which uses one pass without information about being fractional or not, it is useless to do this.

Comment: The relevance of knowing if the interview-challenge assumed signed integers or signed non-integer (fractional/decimal) numbers: if you know as a given that they are integers, you can skip part of the algorithm when the sum is odd. This is in my last bullet point and should be clear enough. Seems useful to me.